# Integrality and normality of ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

Consider a ring $R$, an idela $I$. An element$z\in R$ is **integral** over $I$ if $z$ satisfies the equation
$$z^n+a_1z^{n-1}+\ldots+a_{n-1}z+a_n=0,$$
where $a_i\in I^i$.
We define the **integral closure** $\overline{I}$ of an ideal as the set of elements in $R$ which are integral over $I$ (and this is an ideal of $R$).

We say that $I$ is **integrally closed** if $I=\overline{I}$, and that $I$ is **normal** if all the powers $I^k$ are integrally closed (I'm using Villarreal's *Monomial Algebras*).

**Question**: I'm a bit confused, because from my point of view $I$ is integrally closed if and only if $I$ normal.

**Proof:** If $I$ is normal, then all the powers $I^k$ are integrally closed, hence imposing $k=1$ implies $I$ is integrally closed (maybe here I'm cheating a bit, but Villareal doesn't say anything like $k>1$.

On the other hand, if $I$ is integrally closed, then $I=\overline{I}$ by definition, hence $I^k=\overline{I}^k$ for any $k$.

I strongly suspect there's something wrong (strange to give $2$ different names for the same object), but I can't spot the mistake and I'd like to understand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say "On the other hand, if I is integrally closed, then $I=\bar{I}$ by definition, hence $I^k=\bar{I}^k$ for any k.", but $\bar{I^k} \ne \bar{I}^k$ in general so one cannot conclude from this that $I$ is normal. In fact, integrally closed ideals are frequently not normal. For a simple example, take $R=k[\![x,y]\!]/(x^2,xy)$ and set $\mathfrak{m}=(x,y)$.  Then of course $\mathfrak{m}$ is integrally closed, but, when $k>1$, $\mathfrak{m}^k=(y^k)$.  As the integral closure of any ideal always contains the nilradical of $R$, $x$ must be in the integral closure of any ideal, and so, in particular, $\mathfrak{m}^k$ is not integrally closed when $k>1$.

Comment: Dear @metalspringpro, thanks a lot for your answer! before accepting it, I was just wondering why did you put $[[,]]$ instead of $[,]$... I don't see why your argument is valid only when dealing with formal power series

Comment: @qwertyguy It works just as well taking $R=k[x,y]/(x^2,xy)$; had I read more carefully that you were working through "Monomial Algebra" I would have used that as the example instead. In fact, the argument can be made much more general. Any standard graded $k$-algebra or Noetherian local ring with residue field $k$ has it's maximal (homogeneous in the graded case) ideal not be normal if it is not reduced.